# How to load Only column names from csv file (Pandas)?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I have a large csv file and don't want to load it fully into my memory, I need to get only column names from this csv file. How to load it clearly?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try this:

```
pd.read_csv(file_name, nrows=1).columns.tolist()
```

Answer (score 10):

If you pass `nrows=0` to `read_csv` then it will only load the column row:

```
In[8]:
import pandas as pd
import io
t="""a,b,c,d
0,1,2,3"""
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), nrows=0)

Out[8]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c, d]
Index: []
```

After which accessing attribute `.columns` will give you the columns:

```
In[10]:
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), nrows=0).columns

Out[10]: Index(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], dtype='object')
```